# When I try to build Xcode project from Jenkins, I am getting the error "String index out of range 15"

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I recently installed Jenkins and added required keychains and provisioning profile using "Keychains and Provisioning Profiles" Plugin by following the document https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin but I get this error when I try to build the job.

Also when I build the project from Xcode everything works fine.

```
FATAL: String index out of range: 15
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 15
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at com.sic.plugins.kpp.provider.KPPBaseProvisioningProfilesProvider.removeUUIDFromFileName(KPPBaseProvisioningProfilesProvider.java:171)
at com.sic.plugins.kpp.model.KPPProvisioningProfile.getProvisioningProfileFilePath(KPPProvisioningProfile.java:76)
at com.sic.plugins.kpp.KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.copyProvisioningProfiles(KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.java:157)
at com.sic.plugins.kpp.KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.setUp(KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.java:99)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

Also Jenkins jobs build environment is not able to pick the provisioning profile.[image: Mobile Provisioning Profiles]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? I'm the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

**The above error means you didn't configurate the the provisioning profile.**

***You need to upload your provisioning profile here: `Manage Jenkins` -> `Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management` -> `Upload Keychain or Provisioning Profile File`.***

[image]

***And then you will see the provisioning profile file here.***

[image]

***And then you can select the provisioning profile file from the project configuration.***

[image]

Note:the provisioning profile files downloaded from the Apple developer website will be better than getting from the local directory,because of the names will be changed after imported to Xcode,it's not easy to identify.

Comment: Thank you for your response. An year ago, I tried this solution but it didn't work. Later, when I updated jenkins it automatically worked.

Comment: By the way you dont need to upload there, you can manager inside your project setting.